# Algorithms on flash cards

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e, flashcards

I'm trying to put together flash cards with algorithms on it. I get the following error:

`! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.`

I've got two question:

- What is the reason for this error?
- How can I fix it?

I've got the error using the following code:

```
\documentclass[grid,avery5371]{flashcards}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[ruled,vlined,rightnl,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\geometry{headheight=12pt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\cardbackstyle[\LARGE\bfseries]{plain}
\cardfrontstyle[\large]{headings}


\begin{document}

\begin{flashcard}[graph]{\textsc{dfs}}
  \begin{algorithm}
    \caption{DFS(G)}
    \For{u $\in$ G.V}{
      u.color $\gets$ \textsc{white} \\
      u.$\pi$ $\gets$ \textsc{nil} \\
    }
    \For{u $\in$ G.V}{
      \If{u.color = \textsc{white}}{
        \textsc{dfs-visit}(G, u)
      }
    }
  \end{algorithm}
\end{flashcard}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Aha.  Algorithm2e produces a float, unless you use [H].  Unfortunately, I'm having problems with flashcard even without the algorithm code.

Comment: I had to manually load the avery5371.cfg file (not provided with MikTeX).

Answer (score 1):

At first I thought the text was too big,  but `\cardheight` corresponds to two grid cells.

```
\documentclass[grid,avery5371]{flashcards}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[ruled,vlined,rightnl,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\geometry{headheight=12pt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\cardbackstyle[\LARGE\bfseries]{plain}
\cardfrontstyle[\large]{headings}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{flashcard}[graph]{\textsc{dfs}}
  \scalebox{.8}{\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{DFS(G)}
    \For{u $\in$ G.V}{
      u.color $\gets$ \textsc{white} \\
      u.$\pi$ $\gets$ \textsc{nil} \\
    }
    \For{u $\in$ G.V}{
      \If{u.color = \textsc{white}}{
        \textsc{dfs-visit}(G, u)
      }
    }
  \end{algorithm}}
\end{flashcard}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]